# Run C# code on custom master page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have two files which I only want to include if there isn't a specific get request on the page.

That's the code I'm using on my custom master page:

```
<% if(Request.QueryString["edit"]!=null){ %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteAssets/SP2013Accordion/SP2013Accordion.css" />
    <script src="/SiteAssets/SP2013Accordion/SP2013Accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% } %>
```

But I get this error:

> Error processing /sites/develop_apps/phiterpub/_catalogs/masterpage/newseattle.master. Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

So, apparently I can't run C# code on this page.

I know this was asked before but maybe there is a simple HTML only way of doing it...

Is there any way to run this or a similar function which will be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am proposing a solution on the above scenario where you need not write inline c# code on master page.Also doing that in this case is not elegant for achieving this requirement.

> What you can do is get the query string value "edit" by using javascript and then conditionally load your css and your js files.

Note `getQueryStringParameterByName` this a method which you will have to write to extract the query string value.

```
var edit = getQueryStringParameterByName('edit'); 
if(edit != '')
{
  loadcssFile('/SiteAssets/SP2013Accordion/SP2013Accordion.css');
  loadjsFile('/SiteAssets/SP2013Accordion/SP2013Accordion.css');
}
```

method to load css file

```
 function loadcssFile(cssfile){
 loadcss = document.createElement('link')    
 loadcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
 loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css")    
 loadcss.setAttribute("href", cssfile) 
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss)
 }
```

and the method to load js

```
 function loadjsFile(scriptFile){     
 loadScript = document.createElement('SCRIPT')
 loadScript.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8")
 loadScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")    
 loadScript.setAttribute("src", scriptFile)
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadScript)
 }
```